# trying to record php date("YmdHis") in mysql as integer, but records something unexpected

Tags: php, mysql

`echo date("YmdHis")` see like `20150305072946`

It looks like integer, so i trying to record in mysql as integer.

Mysql column type `int(20)`. Storage Engine is `InnoDB`.

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (`DateTime`) VALUES (?)     
$stmt_insert->execute( array( trim(date("YmdHis")) ) );
```

In mysql instead of `20150305072946` see `2147483647`

What need to correct to insert correct value?

Comment: Why are you not storing it as a `DATETIME`? What you are doing does not make much sense.

Comment: I also use `date("YmdHis")` as part of url. Like `domain/20150305072946/something-else/` If like `domain/2015-03-05-07:2946/something-else/` appears not so good. Need to think ....

Comment: @user2118559: not an argument. In both, PHP and MySQL, exist `date_format` function, so you can store date as date and have this string in your URL.

Comment: Yeah, but how something is stored is not the same as how it is used. Dates should ideally be stored as dates. Once you get the date out of the database you can do with it whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` can't store such big number. `Bigint` is what you need.

**BUT**:
The best way is to save datetime as a `datetime`, there is no reason why to store that as a number.

Comment: Aim was to get faster processing. Supposed that `int` would be faster than `datetime`

Comment: @user2118559: no, as I wrote in the answer above. Store that as a datetime (or timestamp) and use index(es). Integer maybe seems to be a good choice, but isn't. Trust me.

Comment: Excuse me for possibly stupid question. Now in the table column named Id is set as primary. Do i need also `ADD INDEX(`DateTime`);` Add index to column where i store `datetime`?

Comment: @user2118559: if there will be many rows and you will search by date, use index above the date column. If you will have there eg. up to 100 records, you don't need to do it. In general, above table can be more indexes.

Answer (score 2):

This is called interger overflow. This will set the max allowed number in the DB as below which is the maximum signed 32-bit integer

```
2147483647
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

So you need `bigint` datatype for storing bigger integer

Comment: Thanks for answer. Idea to store as integer was with aim to get faster processing (to compare to varchar or datetime). If i store as bigger integer, would processing be same speed as integer (faster than varchar/datetime)?

Comment: @user2118559: save that as a `datetime` and compare dates as dates, not as number and strings. I'm not sure why you want to select, lets say, articles written in last 7 days when you store dates as integers.

Comment: Well processing is a subjective matter. If you want the value in the `select where ...` then using index will make it faster. However its always better to save the date values as mysql native datatypes like `date`,`datetime`,`timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

You need `bigint` datatype for storing bigger integer instead of `int`

Answer (score 1):

this is an minor Problem.

Change the datatype of your table column from **INT** to **bigint**. This will work.

Suppose if your table having column job_id **int** change it to **bigint** same like

Before

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_skills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

After

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_skills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```